# Angular momentum in electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, angular-momentum

I was working on Problem 8.7 in Griffiths Electrodynamics. The setting is like this (I simplified a small bit):

We have two coaxial cylindrical shells with radii $a$ and $b$ along the $z$-axis carrying charges $+Q$ and $-Q$. There is a uniform magnetic field $B\hat{\mathbf{z}}$ out to radius $r$ of the central axis ($a<r<b$). In this case, the angular momentum in the EM field with respect to any reference point on the central axis is the same.

We then slowly discharge the shells by connecting them with a rigid wire. The angular momentum in the field is delivered to the shells by the Lorenz force.  I can get the right angular momentum if I choose the reference point to be at the same $z$-coordinate as the wire.

However, since the situation is no longer cylindrically symmetrical, the torque (and the angular momentum) will depend on the choice of reference point (or, equivalently, where you put the wire). I thought the difference will cancel out if I do the integration in time but I can't get it to work because we don't know how fast the shells are discharged. What's wrong? Where does the extra angular momentum come from?

Comment: I don't think the direction of torque (or angular momentum) depends on where you put the wire. It always seems to be oriented along the $z$-axis regardless.

Comment: It shouldn't but as I understand it, if you, say, put the wire higher, the extra $z$ component of the position vector (using the same reference point) seems to give you some angular momentum $L$ along the $x$-direction. Also, I just realized that this question can be equivalently formulated as asking "The original system has no (field) linear momentum, but the force (summed over time) doesn't necessarily cancel out" since $L$ being independent of reference point is the same as having $0$ total momentum. I hope this is a clearer question.